# jQuery multiple delayed animations inside a loop, animation sometimes not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm making an animated timeline (see jsFiddle below), where the entries (left and right alternately) `fade in` after their specified `delay`. This with the help of a `for`-loop.

If opacity is supported, I'm fading in those entries using `.animate({ opacity: 1 })`.
Else `.fadeIn()`.

With both `.animate()` and `.fadeIn()`, it sometimes happens that the animation of one or more entries is skipped. Note: the chance of this happening seems small.

So my intention, was to check with a `do-while`, inside the main `for`-loop, if the entry is indeed visible, and if not, run the animation again.

However, this seems to cause an infinite loop. Is there maybe a better way to check this, and re-animate?

I've commented out the `do-while` part, in the below jsFiddle.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmmns/B5yUC/1/embedded/result/)

Thanks in advance.

**Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmmns/B5yUC/3/)**, thanks to [sweetamylase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988802/jquery-multiple-delayed-animations-inside-a-loop-animation-sometimes-not-execut/15990065?noredirect=1#15990065).

**Update 2**: I've noticed that another part of my code, a `.hover()` event on the entries, was making them not to appear if my cursor was on an entry when loading the timeline. This was due to the use of `.stop(1, 1).animate()` in that part of my code.

```
$('.timeline .entry').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(1, 1).animate({backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}, 350);

}, function() {
    $(this).stop(1, 1).animate({backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8'}, 350);
});
```

How can I still use `.stop(1, 1)` in this part, so those hover animations won't build up, when fast-hovering?

**Update 3**: I just use a `setTimeout()` now, to allow the `.hover` event only after a specified time.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.timeline .entry').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(1, 1).animate({backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'}, 350);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(1, 1).animate({backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8'}, 350);
    });
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be because you make jQuery look for the entries within each iteration of the loop, **this takes time**, it might be the reason why it sometimes skips the animations on an entry:

```
$('.timeline .entry').eq(i).delay(delays[i]).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```

It is better to minimize the amount of *querying* because that is an expensive operation. So just find the elements once, and iterate through them using the index you already have:

```
var delays = [600, 950, 1200, 1550, 1750, 2300, 2600, 3100, 3750, 4200];
var entries = $('.timeline .entry');

for (var i = 0, numEntries = delays.length; i < numEntries; i++) {
    if (opacitySupport) {
        $(entries[i]).delay(delays[i]).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
    } else {
        $(entries[i]).delay(delays[i]).fadeIn('slow');
    }
}
```

FYI, I used `[]` *array literal notation* instead of calling the Array *constructor* because I find it less confusion-prone: http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/04/the-use-of-literals-vs-constructors/

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch! Your tips on using literal notations regarding arrays and objects, is greatly appreciated as well! It seems to run much smoother now, too.

Comment: Apparently, it was caused by something else. Please see my "Update 2". Still, many thanks for the faster code!